# How to change local push notification icon for React Native iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, push-notification

I'm working with react-native-push-notification package for local notifications. I want to change the default icon that displays on notification. I know I have smallIcon field when setting notification, but how to input my icon into it?

Answer (score -1):

In this package smallIcon is only for android notifications.

Comment: I dont think you answered the question. Its eemphasis is on how to change the icon